# Form using Spring, select an element through jQuery

Tags: jquery, spring

I have a form that used Spring the code is something like this:

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal col-md-12" method="POST" action="../admin/new_laborItem.do" id="laborForm" modelAttribute="laborBean">
    <h5 class="text-info"><strong>Job Definition</strong></h5>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="laborItem" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Item:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <form:input id="laborItem" path="item" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Labor Code"></form:input>
        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

I want to get the text of the text field but I don't know why it doesn't work with this code:

```
console.log($('#laborItem').text());
console.log($('#laborItem').html());
```

The result is empty String.

[image]

I triggered the console after typing **test** in the text field and press a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
$('#laborItem').val()
```

You will need to use [**val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) attr of jQuery to get the value of the input element

Comment: Thank you for introducing me `.val()` tag